# Disabled на js?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, нужно сделать на чистом js чтобы нечто вроде корзинки, а именно при нажатии на кнопку у нее был this.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled"), а по нажатию на крестик возле конкретного элемента списка disabled пропадал, (акцент на том, чтобы пропадал disabled)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const disableButton = document.getElementById('disableButton');
const enableButton = document.getElementById('enableButton');
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

disableButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  //если нужно задать одной кнопке из коллекции, то обращаемся к ней по ключу из коллекции, которые представляет собой номер элемента на странице, нумерация с нуля
  buttons['0'].disabled = true;
  
  //если нужно задать всем кнопкам с классом, то перебираем коллекцию при помощи цикла for of и задаем каждому элементу коллекции
  for (let button of buttons) {
    button.disabled = true;
  }
});

enableButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
   
  buttons['0'].disabled = false;

  for (let button of buttons) {
    button.disabled = false;
  }
  
});
```

```css
#disableButton, #enableButton {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="disableButton">disable buttons</div>
<div id="enableButton">enable buttons</div>
<button class="button">button</button>
<button class="button">button</button>
<button class="button">button</button>
```

Comment: а как по простому сделать через getElementsByClassName("class").disabled=false; только чтобы правильно)

Comment: @РомаПрокопец getElementsByClassName возвращает коллекцию DOM элементов, поэтому, если нужно задать атрибут всем элементам с классом, то нужно перебрать их в цикле(исправил ответ)

Comment: да, у меня есть три кнопки, которые должны дизейблиться и раздизейбливаться)